# how to search several columns in a sql query using concat and UPPER

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a DB and a web page where I want to display the result of my db search

I have try a couple ways both work but they are incomplete for what I want to accomplish

I want to be able to search my table columns id,Id_Nombre,Pais,Estado,Ciudad,website all of them with a word or several words from my search text.

this code works but I have to type exactly the word it's case sensitive:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE concat(id,Id_Nombre,Pais,Estado,Ciudad,website) LIKE '%$Busqueda%'";
```

so as a result i I type a word like "People" in my search box and in my data base that word is type in any of those columns as "people" it wont find it.

second code I use works but only using one column

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE UPPER(Id_Nombre) LIKE UPPER('%$Busqueda%')";
```

the result for this code is great since it will find it no matter the case used, but I need to extend this type of search to all the other columns, but so far everithing I use does not work.

I have tried:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE UPPER(id,Id_Nombre,Pais,Estado,Ciudad,website) LIKE UPPER('%$Busqueda%')";

  $query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE UPPER(concat(id,Id_Nombre,Pais,Estado,Ciudad,website)) LIKE UPPER('%$Busqueda%')";

  $query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE concat(UPPER(id,Id_Nombre,Pais,Estado,Ciudad,website)) LIKE UPPER('%$Busqueda%')";
```

etc.
any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your second example should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it didn't was giving me an boolean error but Miguel-F answer did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try `UPPER` around each column name?  Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Medios_table WHERE concat(UPPER(id),UPPER(Id_Nombre),UPPER(Pais),UPPER(Estado),UPPER(Ciudad),UPPER(website)) LIKE UPPER('%$Busqueda%')";
```

Comment: you got it! I guess I should have try a little more but you save me some valuable time! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your upper(concat(...)) version should work. If you had a problem with that, it's probably just a typo, like you left out a parenthesis or something.

You can't say upper(x,y,z) because upper takes only one parameter. You must do the concat first, then do the upper, i.e. upper(concat(x,y,z)).

That said, this query will be very slow on a big database, because the db engine has to read every record in the table, and then for each one search it character by character. If the table is small or this is done infrequently, that might be acceptable. If the table is big and/or this query will be executed often, you really need a totally different approach.

*Update*

If you really need to search against any text in a field, where you cannot make any assumptions about the text being searched in or the text being searched for in advance, you should investigate fulltext searches. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

If you will be doing these sort of searches all the time, you might want to build a dictionary, that is, build a list of all the word with all the records that that word occurs in. I think that's basically what fulltext does, so this may or may not gain you anything.

But if you have some foreknowledge, that is, if it's not really that you want to search for arbitrary text occurring anywhere in arbitrary text, than break out the things you want to search for into separate fields.

To take a simple example, suppose you have a field that contains customer full name, like "Fred Smith", "Mary Jones", etc. You want to search for someone by last name. You could search for

```
where full_name like '%Smith%'
```

But this would require reading every record in the table. If, instead, you broke the field into first name and last name, then you could search for

```
where last_name='Smith'
```

If you have an index on last_name this would be a very fast search.

If you're just trying to look for an entered value in any of several fields, it is much, much faster to do

```
where estado='Toledo' or ciudad='Toledo' or pais='Toledo'
```

(assuming that you have indexes on estado, ciudad, and pais), then

```
where concat(estado, ciudad, pais) like '%Toledo%'
```

(where no index will do you any good).

If you want to do case-insensitive searches, create an index on upper(estado) instead of on estado, etc. Then "where upper(estado)='TOLEDO'" can use the index.

Also, I'm not sure about MySql, but some database engines can use an index if the LIKE does not begin with a wildcard. That is, "somefield like '%x%'" must read every record in the table. But on some db's, "somefield like 'x%'" can use can index to get to the records where the field starts with "x" and then just process those.

Comment: thats what I thought but it din't work some boolean error was showing but Miguel-F answer did the trick, thanks

Comment: What type of approach would you recommend for a bigger database?

Answer (score 0):

You need full-text search

This link may be useful [Mysql full-text search](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/)